# How to make Inflow object not impact the fluid simulation?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, transparency, fluid-simulation

I'm trying to render an animation of water dancing. I'm using an animation and a character from Mixamo and designated it as the inflow object. The simulation works and follows the character just fine but I want to omit the character in the render so that it's just the water alone. So far I've tried making the character transparent but we can still see it in the render.

Any help is very much appreciated :)

Comment: Hey there and welcome, i am not really sure if the title is perhaps asking something different then the Question-text itself. So please let me ask, is there a problem with the inflow object impacting/affecting the simulation, or is it essentially just a matter of wanting to hide the inflow object from being shown in render?

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering so quickly ! 
I'm pretty new to Blender so i'm not really sure. I thought that even with the object hidden, it would still be discernable on the render because the water would be flowing around the mesh and not in it. Meaning that there would a "gap" where the object should normally be.

Comment: I'd like to know how this "gap" could also be filled with water so that it would only be water dancing and not a person with water around him. 

I hope this clears it up a bit.

Comment: It's slightly hard to imagine which **gap** you mean, so i would suggest to update your question with the [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/176230/edit) button and add some pictures/screenshots elaborating the situation a bit better. Try to make sure that the picture shows the problematic situation, you can of course mark the area if it's not too clear.

Comment: Making the character transparent is not the same as hiding it though. That option can be found in the **Object Properties** under **Visibility**, uncheck the "Show in Viewports/Renders".

Answer (score 0):

After you've baked the simulation you just disable the inflow object entirely from the render. Click the camera icon in the upper right "Outliner" panel.